# What is the point of the .save() function in ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What extra utility does .save() serve? I don't understand why changes to a model aren't saved until you call this function. Is there a reason you would ever not save changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save()` will make the call to the server.

It would be terrible to make server calls every time a property changed (for example on every keyup), so it makes sense to queue up the changes and call save when it's ready (for example hitting submit on a form).